# Doing case analysis on an argument of a macro

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, programming

*Background*: As has been discussed here, there appears to be no widely accepted typographical standard for logical quantifiers.  To address this I defined in my paper the following macro:

```
\newcommand{\zenbu}[1]{\mathop{\forall#1}}
```

so that I can change the typographical convention for quantifiers later.  I use the macro as in, e.g., `\zenbu{\tilde {x_0}}Rxx` or `\zenbu{x \in X}Px`.

Now I like the output of the former example but I'm thinking of changing the output of the latter, i.e., the cases where I put a relation symbol in the argument to typeset the shorthand for quantification over a restricted domain.

*Question*: Is it easy to do this by, in the definition of the macro, branching depending on the content of the argument of the macro?  The relevant relation symbols I use in my paper are `\in` `\sqsubseteq` and `\sqsupseteq`, from AMSLaTeX.

Comment: How would you like the case `x\in X` to be treated?

Comment: @egreg I do not have anything particular in mind.  (I'd like it to be easier to change the look later again.)  But in case it matters, I'd say I want it to look like the output of `(\forall x \in X)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a case branching with `expl3` and `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\zenbu}{m}
 {
  \pteromys_zenbu:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \pteromys_zenbu_in:n
 {
  (\,\forall #1)
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \pteromys_zenbu_sqsubseteq:n
 {
  [\,\forall #1]
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \pteromys_zenbu_sqsupseteq:n
 {
  [\,\forall #1]
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \pteromys_zenbu_generic:n
 {
  \mathop{\forall #1}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \pteromys_zenbu:n
 {
  \tl_if_in:nnTF { #1 } { \in }
   {
    \pteromys_zenbu_in:n { #1 }
   }
   {
    \tl_if_in:nnTF { #1 } { \sqsubseteq }
     {
      \pteromys_zenbu_sqsubseteq:n { #1 }
     }
     {
      \tl_if_in:nnTF { #1 } { \sqsupseteq }
       {
        \pteromys_zenbu_sqsupseteq:n { #1 }
       }
       {
        \pteromys_zenbu_generic:n { #1 }
       }
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\zenbu{x}Px$

$\zenbu{\tilde{x}_0}Rxx$

$\zenbu{x\in X}Px$

$\zenbu{x\sqsubseteq y}Pxy$

$\zenbu{x\sqsupseteq y}Pxy$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a particular reason you inserted \, before the quantifiers?

Comment: @Pteromys Because of clashing glyphs.

Comment: would you think avoiding it here is a good typographical convention?

Comment: @Pteromys Yes, I do, but it's mostly a question of taste and it can depend on the fonts.

Comment: is it easy to adapt this so that the macro branches when it sees in content of the argument a class-3 math symbol?

Comment: @Pteromys Not at all! `;-)`

Comment: Is there any way to avoid the nesting (indent drift) of `tl_if_in`?

Comment: @Noldorin One might think to set up a recursion similar to `\str_case:nnTF`.

Comment: @egreg Okay, thanks. I'll look at the definition of that.